# Probability of Choosing Exactly 2 Men and 7 Women

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose an airline requires 3 pilots and 6 flight attendants to fly.

It has 12 pilots (9 men, 3 women) and 32 flight attendants (6 men, 26 women). The likelihood of choosing a specific person is equal.

What is the probability that a flight has exactly 2 men and 7 women?

My logic is to break this down into 3 cases: 0 male pilots/2 male flight attendants, 1 male pilot/1 male flight attendant, and 2 male pilots/0 male flight attendants. Then the overall probability will be the sum of these.

So for 0 pilots/2 FA:
$$\frac {\binom 9 0  \binom 3 3 \binom 6 2 \binom {26} 4}{\binom {12}  3 \binom {32} 6 }$$

Repeating for all cases and adding them, I get:

$$\frac {\binom 9 0  \binom 3 3 \binom 6 2 \binom {26} 4}{\binom {12}  3 \binom {32} 6 }+\frac {\binom 9 1  \binom 3 2 \binom 6 1 \binom {26} 5}{\binom {12}  3 \binom {32} 6 }+\frac {\binom 9 2  \binom 3 1 \binom 6 0 \binom {26} 6}{\binom {12}  3 \binom {32} 6 }$$

But apparently this is wrong. Where is my logic flawed?

(Also sorry about poor formatting)

Comment: I hope I edited your post correctly Bryden...

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is not flawed at all, but your calculation seems to be. I find the numbers work out to approximately $0.1793$ ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%202%20of%20(9%20choose%20i)*(3%20choose%203-i)%2F(12%20choose%203)*(6%20choose%202-i)*(26%20choose%204%2Bi)%2F(32%20choose%206))).

Comment: Yes it seemed like that was the problem. The first time I manually computed the numbers and I got a number greater than one, so then I just plugged numbers into Desmos at it got the 0.09022. Turns out I put a 5 instead of a 6 which gave me the wrong number. Thanks.